# Bind GridView.ItemsSource back to DataTable but only visible columns and rows

Tags: wpf, gridview, datatable

I know that I can bind ItemsSource of GridView back to DataTable like:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView)myDG.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

But I have 20+ columns, and only 10 of them is visible - how can I get only visible ones?

Thanks

Comment: are you autogenerating columns or manually generated them?

Comment: I have all of 20 declared in xaml, but some of them have indexes (which helps to identify selectedItem), so those ones are nonVisible. For example
1 Product1 20
where 1: productID, Product1: name, 20: price

Comment: I also tried to get only visible columns into List<string> and then : DataTable dt = ((DataView)myDG.ItemsSource).ToTable(true,colList.ToArray()); , but Im getting error Column xxx does not belong to underlying table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have physical columns which are visible then you can directly iterate over datagrid columns collection like

```
IEnumerable<DataGridColumn> visibleColumns = dataGrid.Columns.Where<DataGridColumn>(col => col.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible);
```

and then you can iterate over your DataTable records to get the value of field which has name equal to visibleColumn.Header.

Comment: I dont really understand what You mean. So I need to fill my DataTable like 
DataTable dt = ((DataView)myDG.ItemsSource).ToTable();
and then iterate over that datatable and set row? column? 
I havent mention that myDG is telerik control (known as RadGridView)
EDIT: By the way, as I said in answer for first post I know how to get visible columns (and their headers) but have no idea how to hide them in datatable

Comment: no... once you have the visibleColumns as above you can delete the columns from your DataTable dt which are not in visibleColumns list. So you are left with DataTable with only visible columns